# Who can I turn to for analysis of my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm that attempts to solve SAT, and I believe it always generates the correct result.  It also seems to be extremely efficient by my analysis.  I am looking for a creditable person who is interested enough to try to analyze my algorithm.  It's fairly complicated, but I think that I may have something worthwhile.

Is there a place or some person or people that I can turn to who would be willing to review my algorithm?  I believe I have a novel approach to the problem, and I'm interested in publishing my results.

Comment: Not the right place for this kind of question.

Comment: But where is the correct place for this question?

Comment: @gunner why not? If you post the algorithm, you can ask for specific analysis HERE.

Comment: @San Jacinto: Actually this site is for direct questions that require direct answer. The link provided by Brian Ramsay is more more appropriate for such posts.

Comment: @Gunner it's been many times such a question was asked and answered. If you ask specific things, it gets answered. If you say: "analyze my algorithm for me," it gets closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Analyze the algorithm as best as you can yourself and write a paper about it, with all the usual ingredients (explanation of your novel ideas, comparison to other algorithms, benchmarks, ...), then submit it to an appropriate conference ([CAV](http://www-cav2009.imag.fr/)? [CADE](http://www.cadeinc.org/)?).

Comment: Your link to CADE seems to be broken - but thanks for the ideas otherwise